# Java Home keeps reverting back to JRE but I need JDK

Tags: gradle, spring-test

I have gone to  `Windows -> Preferences -> Java -> install JRE's` and placed my `jdk 10` file inside. Still there but not being read

I went to `computer -> right click properties -> advance systems-> added` `JAVA_HOME` to the `systems variables`

I also went to run as -> run configurations -> Environments  and tried placing the Java 10 path inside there but gave me an error when running my spring batch test.

I been to almost everywhere to try and get the Java home to read the JDK but it still shows as a JRE:

```
Working Directory: C:\Users\git\paymentportalbatchjob
Gradle User Home: C:\Users\.gradle
Gradle Distribution: Local installation at 
C:\Users\Software\gradle-4.10.2-bin\gradle-4.10.2
Gradle Version: 4.10.2
-> Java Home: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_171 <-
JVM Arguments: None
Program Arguments: None
Build Scans Enabled: false
Offline Mode Enabled: false
Tests: com.ecom.BatchTest
```

Error:

```
  > Task :bootBuildInfo
  > Task :compileJava FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
> Could not target platform: 'Java SE 10' using tool chain: 'JDK 8 (1.8)'.
```

EDIT: I decided it delete the java 1.8 and now it shows JAVA HOME as 10 however its the JRE and not the JDK, I get a new error. (Both JRE 0 and JDK 10 are in the same folder)

```
Working Directory: C:\Users\git\rxdpf-paymentportalbatchjob
Gradle User Home: C:\Users\.gradle
Gradle Distribution: Local installation at C:\Users\Software\gradle- 
4.10.2-bin\gradle-4.10.2
Gradle Version: 4.10.2
Java Home: C:\Program Files\Java\jre-10.0.1
JVM Arguments: None
Program Arguments: None
Build Scans Enabled: false
Offline Mode Enabled: false
Tests: com.ecom.BatchTest#setupMongo
```

NEW ERROR:

```
> Configure project :
createDockerfile
createDockerfile

> Task :bootBuildInfo
> Task :compileJava FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
> Cannot find System Java Compiler. Ensure that you have installed a JDK 
(not just a JRE) and configured your JAVA_HOME system variable to point to 
the according directory.
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured a short term solution. The JAVA_HOME still reverts back to the JRE, but if you click

```
> run as -> run configuration -> gradle project, chose your project ->
> Java home -> add your jdk file and click run.
```

It did the trick for me. But I ave to repeat these steps when I want to run a gradle test

```
Working Directory: C:\Users\git\rxdpf-paymentportalbatchjob
Gradle User Home: C:\Users\.gradle
Gradle Distribution: Local installation at C:\Users\Software\gradle-4.10.2-bin\gradle-4.10.2
Gradle Version: 4.10.2
Java Home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.1
JVM Arguments: None
Program Arguments: None
Build Scans Enabled: false
Offline Mode Enabled: false
Gradle Tasks: testClasses


> Configure project :
createDockerfile
createDockerfile

> Task :bootBuildInfo
> Task :compileJava UP-TO-DATE
> Task :generateGitProperties UP-TO-DATE
> Task :processResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :classes
> Task :compileTestJava
> Task :processTestResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :testClasses

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 5.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/4.10.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 7s
5 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 3 up-to-date
```